# How convert string to ComboBoxModel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I have 2 jframe. What I want is that the value of nit "555" can be seen in the comboBox of the second jframe, The data entered is stored in CompanyClass

[image]

[image]

```
comboBoxName.setModel(new CompanyClass().getNit());
```

getNit it's a string

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Don't **ask** for a `String`. Ask for the `ComboBoxModel`!

Answer (score 3):

Try below statements

```
    String[] content = {"A", "B"}; // Here you can have model eg: CompanyClass
    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>();
    ComboBoxModel<String> model = cb.getModel();

    if (model instanceof DefaultComboBoxModel) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = (DefaultComboBoxModel) model;
        dcbm.removeAllElements();
        for (String value : content) {
            dcbm.addElement(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define Labels for model.

```
String labels[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(labels);
JComboBox comboBoxName = new JComboBox();
comboBoxName.setModel(model);
```